# Prove that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{k^2}{e^k}< \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{k}{2^k}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, constants

Prove that :

> > $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{k^2}{e^k}< \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{k}{2^k}$$

Without calculating the value of these series .

The partial sum formula are :

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{2^k} = 2^{-n}(-n+2^{n+1}-2)$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k^2}{e^k} =\frac{ (e^{-n} (-e^2 n^2 + 2 e n^2 - n^2 - 2 e^2 n + 2 e n + e^{n + 1} + e^{n + 2} - e^2 - e))}{(e - 1)^3}$$

I have tried a straightforward comparison like :

$$\frac{x^2}{e^x}\leq \frac{x}{2^x}$$

Wich is true for $x\geq 6$

So we have a problem with the first terms .

If you have a trick (maybe using integral) or a good answer I take .

Any helps is appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you can find a single value of $n\ge5$ such that $\sum_1^n(k^2/e^k)\le\sum_1^n(k/2^k)$ then you can combine it with the comparison inequality you have found for the win.

Comment: I'm really sorry, but imho, this question makes about as much sense as "prove 1.1 < 1.2 without referring to their numerical value".

Comment: I'm sorry too (I like this kind of question), but I'm inclined to agree with @ProfessorVector. The inequality is equivalent to $e > 2.7148.$ That's closer than the fifth continued fraction convergent $\frac{19}7 \bumpeq2.7143.$ Do you have reason to think that such a good approximation to $e$ can be derived by comparing these series? Without a compelling reason to do it that way, the natural thing to do is approximate $e$ in any convenient way, such as taking the seventh continued fraction convergent $\frac{106}{39} \bumpeq 2.7179,$ and use the known exact sums of the series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{11}(\frac{k^2}{e^k}-\frac{k}{2^k}) = -0.002905
$$

Further, include your finding that for $x > 6$,
$$
\frac{x^2}{e^x}-  \frac{x}{2^x} \leq 0
$$

This shows that the partial sum for more than 11 terms will always obey the required inequality, hence also the infinite sum.

Comment: So, the strategy I suggested in the comments works. Good!

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes!

Answer (score 0):

*Thsi is not very rigorous.*

Let $$a_n=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k^2}{e^k}} { \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k}{2^k}}$$ Using the partial sums you gave
$$a_n=\left(\frac{2}{e}\right)^n \frac{-e^2 n^2+2 e n^2-n^2-2 e^2 n+2 e n+e^{n+1}+e^{n+2}-e^2-e}{(e-1)^3
   \left(-n+2^{n+1}-2\right)}$$ The numerator is basically driven by $\left(e^{n+1}+e^{n+2}\right)$ and the denominator is almost $(e-1)^3\, 2^{n+1}$. So, at he limit
$$a_n \sim \left(\frac{2}{e}\right)^n \frac{e^{n+1}+e^{n+2}}{(e-1)^3\, 2^{n+1}}=\frac{e (e+1)}{2 (e-1)^3}\approx 0.996147$$